# Ruby on Rails: Keep user input after submitting search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, drop-down-menu

Quick question. When submitting a search, some of my fields save the user input in the text field or drop down menu after the search has been done, but for other fields, it reverts back to the default choice. How do I make them save the users choice.

```
    Start date:
<%= select_tag "start_date_dd", options_for_select({
    "Select a period" => "",
      "3 days ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 3.days,   # =    259_200 sec.
      "1 week ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.week,   # =    604_800 sec.
      "1 month ago"  => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.month,  # =  2_592_000 sec.
      "6 months ago" => DateTime.now.to_date - 6.months, # = 15_552_000 sec.
      "1 year ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.year,   # = 31_557_600 sec.
    }, :selected=>params[:start_date_dd] )%></br>



Status :

<%= select(@projects, :status, Project.all.map {|p| [p.status]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:status]) %></br>
```

Here my status dropdown box keeps the user input in the text box, but my start date drop down menu does not. Any way around this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:selected => params[:status] is why your status drop box keeps the value
you would need to add :selected=>params[:start_date_dd] added to the tag

Comment: is there a reason you are mixing select tag and select helper in the same form? also are you doing anything with the params hash in the controller?

Comment: Can I direct you to my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796225/ruby-on-rails-search-form-multiple-search-fields-including-dates-date-picker) I posted today. All of my code is there. Maybe you can help me? Thanks again